# Pandas datetime64 problem (datetime introduces spikes in data)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so be kind :)
I work with imported csv files and pandas and really liked the pandas datetime possibilities to work and filter dataframes. But i have serious problems with plotting the data in a neat way when using dates as datetime64. Either when using pandas plots or seaborn plots.
my csv looks like this:

```
    date time   Flux_ConNT_C    Flux_ConB1  Flux_ConB2  Flux_ConB3  Flux_ConB4  Flux_ConB4
0   01.01.2015 00:30    2.552032129 2.193558665 1.0093326   1.013124869 1.159512896 1.159512896

1   01.01.2015 01:00    2.553308464 2.195533756 1.01003938  1.013935693 1.160672989 1.160672989

2   01.01.2015 01:30    2.554585438 2.197510626 1.010746655 1.014747166 1.161834243 1.161834243

3   01.01.2015 02:00    2.55586305  2.199489276 1.011454426 1.015559289 1.162996658 1.162996658

4   01.01.2015 02:30    2.557141301 2.201469707 1.012162692 1.016372061 1.164160236 1.164160236
```

when I plot the data with

```
df.plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

my output is [right output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Ytl.png)

but when I change the "date time" column to 'datetime64 with

```
df['date time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date time'])
```

and use the same code to plot, the data is plotted with these spikes and its not usable [false output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edf6N.png)

There seems to be a problem with matplotlib, but i can't find anything else than putting `register_matplotlib_converters()` before the plot, which doesn't change anything.
I'm working with Spyder IDE and Python 3.7 and all libraries are up to date.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is no miracle, it's simply not reproduciable.

1. Are you sure your csv doesn't have a header for the first index column 0..4?
2. Are you sure in the csv column 8 is a duplicate of column 7?
3. How did you actually import this csv and construct your dataframe?
4. The first plot only works after replaceing the range index 0..4 by the "date time" column. What other transformations did you apply to the dataframe before calling the plot method?
5. Your *to_datetime* conversion only works on a column, not an index. Why don't you share all the code that you've been using?
6. In the 2 plots the first 5 rows don't don't differ. Why don't you share the data rows that are actually different in the 2 plots?

I will give you credit for trying to abstract the problem properly. Unfortunately, you omitted important information. Based on the limited information you've been showing here, there is no problem at all.

To make my point clear: What you observed is not related to the datetime64[ns] conversion, but to something probably very simple that you didn't consider important enough to share with us.

Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The idea is: When you're able to prepare your problem in a reproduciable way, you'll probably be ab le to solve it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Peter, my problem was that `df['date time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date time'])` messed up the dates and switched "y-m-d" to" y-d-m" at some points in the dataframe, resulting in these peaks. The problem was solved by setting the datetime in the pd.read_csv argument like `df=pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['date time'], dayfirst=True)`